# Width of Depletion region, barrier potential

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Why does the width of Depletion region and Barrier potential in case of p-n junction diode decrease when there is an increase in temperature?

Answer (score 0):

Barrier potential is caused due to electrostatic potential of diffused minority carriers from p side to n side and vice versa. Now they form a capacitor-like distribution of charge which is insulated by an absence of majority carriers. When we increase the temperature we cause more random oscillations of the majority carriers which then break the insulation and annihilate the diffused minority carriers and in turn decrease the barrier potential. It is helpful to note that more is the diffused charge, more will be the barrier potential.